# Understanding independence. Sample space $S = \{1,2,3,\ldots,20\}$ and events $A_n = \{x \in S: x \: \text{is a multiple of} \:n\}$

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

[image]

The one in blue are the solution. $x$ is the multiple of $n$ which mean $A_2$ should equal to $4$ right? and $P(A_2)$ should equal to $1/5$ (As $2/20$). Why in the solution, $P(A_2) = 1/2$ ?

Please help me explain. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: look at the "Note." in the solution. It indicates that $|A_2|=10.$ That's because $A_2=\{2,4,6,\ldots,20\}.$

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. 1/5 is not equal to 2/20, and $A_2$ is a set, so it should not “equal to 4.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S = \{1,2,3,\ldots,20\}$

$A_n = \{x \in S: x \: \text{is a multiple of} \:n\}$ $\:\:\:n=1,2,3,\ldots$

$A_1 = \{1,2,3,\ldots,20\}$

$A_2 = \{2,4,6,\ldots,20\}$

because the products of $n=2$ with the elements in $S$ are

$2,4,6,\ldots,20$

up to $20$ because we have the restriction that $x \in S$.

So $1 \leq x \leq 20$

$A_3 = \{3,6,9,\ldots,18\}$

and so on.

$$P(A_2) =\frac{|A_2|}{|S|} =\frac{10}{20}$$

And to explain independence:

The events $U$ and $V$ are independent if $P(U) = P(U \mid V)$ because the result of one event has no influence on the result of the other.

edit:

The conditional probability of an event $U$ given an event $V$, denoted by

$P(U \mid V)$ is defined as

$$P(U \mid V) = \frac{P(U \cap V)}{P(V)}$$

where $P(U \cap V)$ is the joint probability of $U$ and $V$, or more commonly called the intersection.

In your case we have

$$P(A_2 \mid A_3) = \frac{P(A_2 \cap A_3)}{P(A_3)} = \frac{|\{6,12,18\}|}{|\{3,6,9,\ldots,18\}|} = \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$\{6,12,18\}$ are in both event $A_2$ and $A_3$.

Comment: Could you please help explain P(A2 | A3) ? Thank you

Comment: Yes sir! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$A_2=\left\{2,4,6,8,\ldots,20 \right\}$, the even numbers.

$$P(A_2)=\frac{10}{20}=\frac{1}{2}$$